# TYPO3 ERROR: Carousel content element has no rendering definition

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have added a carousel content element on my webpage, but it is not showing up. Instead I get the following error message:

ERROR: Content Element with uid "259" and type "carousel" has no rendering definition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you've installed the bootstrap_package extension?
If yes you should include the static template of it on your root page.
Root -> Templates -> Includes

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the steps outlined in [Adding your own content elements](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html). In your case you are most likely missing the registration of your custom content element in the `tt_content` rendering registry:

```
tt_content {
   carousel =< lib.contentElement
   carousel {
      templateName = Carousel
   }
}
```

Side note: you should always include your extension name in content types. So given a extension `foo_bar` you would name your content element `foobar_carousel`. This avoids conflicts with other extensions shipping similarly named content.

Comment: I'm referring to the standard carousel element that comes with Typo3 out of the box. I did not add my own content element. Also in which file do I register the tt_content?

Comment: TYPO3 does not ship a carousel element by default so you have most likely installed a 3rd party extension for this.

Comment: Yes,sorry, you are right. I am using bootstrap. I'm still wondering though, in which folder can I find the tt_content rendering registry?

Comment: There is no folder, the registry is build at runtime based on TypoScript configuration from all extensions. You can see the active state in the TypoScript Object Browser within the _Template_ backend module.